# ClassNotFoundException commonsware CameraFragment

Tags: java, android, commonsware-cwac

I'm trying to implement this library:
https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera

So after setting up ActionBarSherlock (needed for older APIS than 10), when I run the App it's crashing while inflating the layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.commonsware.cwac.camera.acl.CameraFragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

with the following error:

[image]

This is my library setup:

[image]

Everything compiles but as soon as I'm using this class in layout, it's crashing.

It's imported because I can use that class in code:

[image]

Any tips?

Edit:

This is my actual setup. Instead of using Jar, I'm now using sourcecode as library project, now the error looks like AppCompat library is incompatible with Sherlock and/or CameraFragment library:

[image]

[image]

**2nd EDIT.**
Now, I removed ABS from the project and used Appcompat for Commonsware Camera Project. It compiles, and the error is now the following:

> Class is not a View com.commonsware.cwac.camera.acl.CameraFragment

Comment: Sorry, bit off topic, but you don't need ABS anymore. There is a SupportActionBar in [support-library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html). ABS is still working but support of other libraries for ABS might decrease..

Comment: I'm not using ABS, https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera does need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CameraFragment` is not a `View`, and so you cannot use it as such. Either use a `<fragment>` element to use the fragment, or use `CameraView`.